# How Can I Decide Which Resultset is Better Than the Other With Wilcoxon Ranksum Test?

Tags: python, optimization

I have runned two different meta-heuristic algorithm for 25 times and I want to check which algorithm's results are better than the other algorithm. I decided to use Wilcoxon Ranksum test but I could not understood well the output of the given function:

```
from scipy.stats import ranksums
rng = np.random.default_rng()
sample1 = rng.uniform(-1, 1, 200)
sample2 = rng.uniform(-0.5, 1.5, 200)
ranksums(sample1, sample2)
Output: RanksumsResult(statistic=-7.887059, pvalue=3.09390448e-15)

ranksums(sample1, sample2, alternative='less')
Output: RanksumsResult(statistic=-7.750585297581713, pvalue=4.573497606342543e-15)

ranksums(sample1, sample2, alternative='greater')
Output: RanksumsResult(statistic=-7.750585297581713, pvalue=0.9999999999999954)
```

How can I understand which sample is better than the other? I think sample2 is better, becuase in the second output pvalue is lower than 0.05 and the alternative parameter is "less". Can anyone explain this code and output?

Answer (score 0):

The test does not tell you which sample is better; that's up to you to decide.

From the documentation:

> The Wilcoxon rank-sum test tests the null hypothesis that two sets of measurements are drawn from the same distribution.

The test only answers the question: are the samples "statistically different"?
If you have no prior expectation which sample should be better just use the default two-sided alternative hypothesis.

Once you are confident they are different (p-value below a pre-determined threshold), you can proceed to determine which sample is better. How to define "better" depends on the metric you are comparing (e.g. errors should be smaller, scores should be larger, ...).